# Como passar uma classe com atributo BigDecimal e Date por meio de intents(Bundle)?

Tags: java, android

Eu tenho um `ArrayList<MinhaClasse>` com atributo BigDecimal e estou passando por intent de uma atividade para outra. 
O problema é que o atributo BigDecimal passa com valor null.

Será que não dá para passar um atributo BigDecimal? 
Eu estou com um atributo date com mesmo problema.

Comment: O que a MinhaClasse implementa, Serializable ou Parcelable?

Comment: Ela implementa Parcelable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem(pelo menos) duas possibilidades:

- Fazer MinhaClasse implementar Serializable, o que não é aconselhável para este efeito<sup>(1)</sup>.
  Date e BigDecimal implementam Serializable, eles serão processados sem problema.
  Deve usar `getSerializableExtra()`em vez de `getParcelableExtra()`.
- Alterar a MinhaClasse de forma a guardar no Parcel uma `String` e um `long` com os valores do BigDecimal e da Date. Eles, depois de recuperados, são usados para os recriar.

  ```
  public class ClassParcelable implements Parcelable{

      private Date someDate;
      private BigDecimal someBigValue;

      public ClassParcelable(Date someDate, BigDecimal someBigValue){
          this.someDate = someDate;
          this.someBigValue = someBigValue;
      }

      //Implementação da Parcelable

      @Override
      public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

          //Guarda um long que representa a data
          dest.writeLong(someDate.getTime());

          //Guarda uma String com a representação do valor do BigDecimal
          dest.writeString(someBigValue.toPlainString());
      }

      protected ClassParcelable(Parcel in) {

          //Recupera o long que representa a data e recria-a
          someDate = new Date(in.readLong());
          //Recupera a String que representa o valor do BigDecimal e recria-o
          someBigValue = new BigDecimal(in.readString());
      }

      @Override
      public int describeContents() {
          return 0;
      }

      public static final Creator<ClassParcelable> CREATOR = new Creator<ClassParcelable>() {
          @Override
          public ClassParcelable createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
              return new ClassParcelable(in);
          }

          @Override
          public ClassParcelable[] newArray(int size) {
              return new ClassParcelable[size];
          }
      };
  }
  ```

<sub><sup>(1)</sup> - É usada reflexão durante o processo e muitos objetos adicionais são criados, o que pode causar muita colecta de lixo. O resultado é um desempenho fraco e elevado consumo da bateria.</sub>

Comment: Muito Obrigado vou tentar o procedimento

Comment: Esse ramaral salva a vida da gente sempre.

Comment: Tinha até esquecido desse post kkkk, Bigdecimal é muito ruim de trabalhar não vejo vantagem.